# Car engine warm-up cycle

Tags: warmup, cold-weather

My 2014 accord has an automatic transmission with a setting that allows you to run the engine at 2-3k rpm while traveling at neighborhood speeds.  Is there any situation involving Minnesota-style cold weather under which making use of this feature would improve the warm-up cycle?  That is, shorten the warm-up cycle while having minimal impact on engine wear?  Are there weather conditions where there would be a benefit, even though there may be other situations where this would not be a good idea?  Would this practice have different impact on 4-cyl engines vs V6 engines?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Do you plug your car in up there in MN? If so, this is a much better option than running your car in the "warm up" mode you describe. Warm up is where the largest portion of wear comes from while running the engine. Running it at higher RPMs makes it even worse. To me, this mode you describe is a recipe for disaster, but that's JMHO.